How to get NullInjectorError information for Android in Chrome's Inspect Devices
I have an Ionic Angular project which is working fine in the browser, but gives a NullInjectorError on Android devices.
In order to trace back where the error comes from, I have an Android device connected to the PC and do the inspection with Google Chrome's chrome://inspect/#devices.
The output in Chrome looks like this:
main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1 ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[t -> InjectionToken  -> [object Object] -> Bs -> Bs]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Bs!
    at $i.get (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1172772)
    at zi.get (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1176195)
    at zi.get (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1176195)
    at nn (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1171275)
    at An (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1171352)
    at ir (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1171790)
    at Object.i [as factory] (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1178483)
    at zi.hydrate (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1177523)
    at zi.get (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1176148)
    at nn (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1171275)
handleError @ main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1
polyfills.132a08611f4a15c8.js:1 NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError[t -> InjectionToken  -> [object Object] -> Bs -> Bs]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for Bs!
    at $i.get (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1172772)
    at zi.get (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1176195)
    at zi.get (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1176195)
    at nn (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1171275)
    at An (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1171352)
    at ir (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1171790)
    at Object.i [as factory] (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1178483)
    at zi.hydrate (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1177523)
    at zi.get (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1176148)
    at nn (main.f1c1bc206c0c555f.js:1:1171275)

So this fails to tell me which provider is missing or wrong.
How can I get the development type of output for this?
This is what the main.ts file looks like:
import { enableProdMode, importProvidersFrom } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { IonicModule,isPlatform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';
import { provideHttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { provideFirebaseApp, initializeApp } from '@angular/fire/app';
import { browserLocalPersistence, indexedDBLocalPersistence, provideAuth, getAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { routes } from './app/app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app/app.component';
import { IonicStorageModule } from '@ionic/storage-angular';
import { ServiceWorkerModule } from '@angular/service-worker';

import { firebaseConfiguration } from './app/config/app.config';

enableProdMode();

bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter(routes),
    provideHttpClient(),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(firebaseConfiguration)),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (isPlatform('android')) {
        auth.setPersistence(indexedDBLocalPersistence);
      } 
      else {
        auth.setPersistence(browserLocalPersistence);
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    importProvidersFrom(
      IonicModule.forRoot(),
      IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
      ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
        enabled: !isPlatform('android'),
      })
    ),
  ],
});


In order to debug the issue, you need to build the app in a configuration where there is no optimization and minification of the code, afterwards you should see a proper error message with the name of the affected provider. Usually when building the app and not providing any config, a production build is made which obscures the code, which makes this error message unuseful.

@NorthFred you can turn on sourceMaps and run a build then check the stacktrace

@NarenMurali The problem is that this error occurs immediately at the start of launching the app.

Also, when I try to debug with the command ionic cap run android -l --external the app works perfectly fine without the NullInjector errors.

@JSONDerulo I did so using the command ionic capacitor build android --configuration development, but there the app works perfectly fine. I only seem to get the error when I create a production or optimized build. I'm out of ideas :/

@NorthFred try to catch the error in debugger and look into that Bs, to most likely see what is the class that is missing from providers

@Andrei I could use some help on how to do the debugging. The error happens right at the start of launching the app, so SourceMap doesn't give me any additional info...

simple way is to look for Bs in compiled sources. in most cases methods aren't renamed and probably by those methods it is easy to understand what class is that

@Andrei I tried this, but the class doesn't contain any useful information.

The most likely cause is, that a release build is not supposed to be debuggable = true; when the intent is to debug a minified (release) build, you'd somehow have to add a custom staging build-type.

@Martin Zeitler As soon as I use the "optimization": false flag in angular.json, it works fine.

That's probably JS dead-code elimination and there's not much to do about it, except switching it on or off (it might be assumed, that this class is not required, as it's not meant to debug that build anyway). https://v17.angular.io/guide/workspace-config#optimization-configuration

NullInjectorErrors are usually an improper import and/or a provider that is on one of your components or modules. you must go 1 by 1 and add/remove each one to see which is the problem. yes it is tedious. goodluck!

I have got solution for this.
Actually earlier we were injecting dependencies inside constructor like:
constructor(private varName: ClassName) {}

Because of this we are getting above null Injector error.
Solution: Inject all dependecies as below
// Outside constructor
private varName = inject(ClassName);

and error will be gone.

I tried this approach but still have the same NullInjector errors.

Worked for me at night and now in the morning again not working for me also. I am trying will post again.

Do you have any update to share on this?
